# Trying to Authorize a ClaimsIdentity in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity

I added some code to my controller to for it to authorize all users:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("/api/{companyIdentifier}/My")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
```

In a custom middleware app I added the following logic that builds off a jwt claim.

```
   var validateTokenResult =handler.ValidateToken(tokenString, parameters,out outvariable);

                if (validateTokenResult.Identity != null)
                {
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(validateTokenResult.Claims)
                    {
                        Label = "Middleware Bearer Auth"

                    };

                    context.User.AddIdentity(identity);

                }
```

I am still getting a 401 Unauthorized.  When debugging I can see that after adding the identity there are 2 identities.  One has no claims and the second has several claims and is set to isAuthenticated:true.  Any idea what could be going on here.  I am guessing the first identity should not have been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed something strange in my logs:

> 2017-02-08 15:35:23.9356 Authorization was successful for user:
>   (null).

Instead of adding the identity to the current httpcontext.user I just replaced the the user with the new one that was created by the token validation:

`context.User = validateTokenResult;`

This solved the problem for me.